# Unable to login using ssh PuTTY

Tags: git, ssh, putty

I'm facing a weird problem with ssh login using PuTTY to "git.xxx.com".
Weirdest thing is using same privateKey file I can login successfully with my Windows 7 machine,
but not with my Win XP machine.
On entering the passphrase it simply hangs - no messages are displayed.
No idea what blocks in XP. Can anyone advise.

Comment: If you are not being given "wrong passphrase" and asked to try again, then your password should be correct. Do you have any firewalls running on the machine that could be inhibiting the port you're using for SSH (22, by default)? If there are, does disabling them (temporarily) and trying again fix the problem?

Comment: Using the same settings (default port 22) I can connect successfully to svn server from my xp. but not git.